# Share hash map between thread in jmeter with beanshell scripting

Tags: performance, jmeter, share, beanshell

J meter script contain two thread. Thread 01 is a setup thread and it loop 'n' times before executing thread 2 which is the test.
I have implemented two beanshell processors in both threads and include below code.

Thread 01:(set up thread) >> Used Beanshell post processor

```
String mapKey=vars.get("count_id");
String refresh_Token = vars.get("refreshToken");
Map refreshCodeMap = new HashMap();
refreshCodeMap.put(mapKey,refresh_Token);

log.info(mapKey + "Map key");
log.info(refresh_Token + "refresh Token");  

bsh.shared.refreshCodeMap= refreshCodeMap;
```

Thread 02: (Test) >> used beanshell pre porocessor

```
String count_id=vars.get("count_id");
Map refreshCodeMap = bsh.shared.refreshCodeMap;
log.info(count_id);
log.info(refreshCodeMap.get(count_id));
```

But in thread o1, Out put is as below.

```
2019-09-20 08:41:57,194 INFO o.a.j.u.BeanShellTestElement: 1
2019-09-20 08:41:57,194 INFO o.a.j.u.BeanShellTestElement: null
2019-09-20 08:41:57,210 INFO o.a.j.u.BeanShellTestElement: 2
2019-09-20 08:41:57,211 INFO o.a.j.u.BeanShellTestElement: null
2019-09-20 08:41:57,224 INFO o.a.j.u.BeanShellTestElement: 3
2019-09-20 08:41:57,224 INFO o.a.j.u.BeanShellTestElement: null
2019-09-20 08:41:57,234 INFO o.a.j.u.BeanShellTestElement: 4
2019-09-20 08:41:57,234 INFO o.a.j.u.BeanShellTestElement: null
2019-09-20 08:41:57,243 INFO o.a.j.u.BeanShellTestElement: 5
2019-09-20 08:41:57,243 INFO o.a.j.u.BeanShellTestElement: null
2019-09-20 08:41:57,252 INFO o.a.j.u.BeanShellTestElement: 6
2019-09-20 08:41:57,253 INFO o.a.j.u.BeanShellTestElement: null
2019-09-20 08:41:57,260 INFO o.a.j.u.BeanShellTestElement: 7
2019-09-20 08:41:57,260 INFO o.a.j.u.BeanShellTestElement: null
2019-09-20 08:41:57,265 INFO o.a.j.u.BeanShellTestElement: 8
2019-09-20 08:41:57,265 INFO o.a.j.u.BeanShellTestElement: null
2019-09-20 08:41:57,270 INFO o.a.j.u.BeanShellTestElement: 9
2019-09-20 08:41:57,270 INFO o.a.j.u.BeanShellTestElement: null
2019-09-20 08:41:57,275 INFO o.a.j.u.BeanShellTestElement: 10
2019-09-20 08:41:57,275 INFO o.a.j.u.BeanShellTestElement: 2f889ccd-acfe-3345-bc68-21a52e71c8e2
```

Here define hashmap is get overrite in every loop in thread 1 execution. Therefore hash map contains only the last loop execution data. I need to assign all the values created in thread 01 execution and get them in thread 2.
 Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all be aware that [since JMeter 3.1 it is recommended to use JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language for scripting](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting). There is no `bsh.shared` namespace in Groovy however you can achieve the same using [`props` shorthand](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy/) which can be used for passing variables across threads and thread groups.

1. In first Thread Group:

   ```
   def refreshCodeMap = new HashMap()
   if (props.get('refreshCodeMap') != null) {
       refreshCodeMap = props.get('refreshCodeMap')
   }

   refreshCodeMap.put(vars.get('count_id'),vars.get('refreshToken'))
   props.put('refreshCodeMap', refreshCodeMap)
   ```
2. In second Thread Group:

   ```
   def count_id=vars.get('count_id')
   def refreshCodeMap = props.get('refreshCodeMap')
   log.info(count_id)
   log.info(refreshCodeMap.get(count_id))
   ```

Demo:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I have tried this with beanshell scripting and defined the hash map within the Test plan and and shared.  My jmeter version is 3.3. But once I restart the jmeter and execute the test I  got error intermittently. [1]